# ViewResult.ExecuteResult taking too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have an asp.net mvc4 application, and when I publish it to azure it's taking too long to load pages. I installed glimpse to check where is the problem, and it showed me that ViewResult.ExecuteResult is the one that is taking most of the time (actually > 1 minute), how can I check why is this taking too much time to execute?

Comment: Does it happen on every load of the same page or only on the first load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it was my fault. I had intellitrace on, after I turn it off the site is working normally.

Comment: I have a similar issue, although not on Azure, can I ask what you mean by turning off intellisense (might be a dumb question)

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it's intellitrace, not intellisense

Comment: @Escobar5 can you tell how we can turn off ? and from where ?